# Plotly: How to plot histogram with x=hour?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, jupyter, plotly-python

I have a series of data with only rows below

```
Time,Component
9:32,System
9:32,Class
9:32,System
9:32,System
9:32,System
9:32,Class
9:32,System
9:32,Class
9:32,System
9:32,System
9:32,Class
9:32,Class
9:32,System
9:32,System
9:32,System
9:32,Class
9:32,Class
9:32,System
9:32,Class
```

How do I plot a histogram with X-axis is the time series by hourly and Y-axis will be the count of the Components happen in that hour.

I tried below but it does not show any data.

```
import plotly.express as px
series['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(series['Time'])
df = series
fig2 = px.histogram(df, x=df.datetime, y=df.Component, histfunc='sum', title='Histogram Chart')
fig2.show(renderer="iframe_connected")
```

Comment: Good of you to mark one of the suggested solutions as the accepted answer. While I find it a bit strange that you went for a matplotlib suggestion while using plotly, that's entirely up to you.  Anyhow, by now you've also gained enough rep to award useful suggestions with your upvotes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
Component_count = df['Component'].resample('H').count()
Time_Component_count = pd.DataFrame({'Time': Component_count.index, 'Component Count': Complonent_count.values})

plt.hist(x = Time_Component_count['Time'], y = Time_Component_count['Component Count'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're using pandas, you can do this by creating a [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) while using [grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to aggregate the values per hour:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['9:32', 'System'], ['9:32', 'Class'], ['9:32', 'System'], ['9:32', 'System'], ['9:32', 'System'], ['9:32', 'Class'], ['9:32', 'System'], ['9:32', 'Class'], ['10:32', 'System'], ['10:32', 'System'], ['10:32', 'Class'], ['11:22', 'Class'], ['11:22', 'System'], ['11:22', 'System'], ['11:32', 'System'], ['11:32', 'Class'], ['11:32', 'Class'], ['12:32', 'System'], ['12:32', 'Class']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Time','Component'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']) # convert Time to datetime object 
df.pivot_table(index=pd.Grouper(key = 'Time', freq = 'H'), columns='Component', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).plot(kind='bar')
```

result:

[image: result]

If you wish to plot the chart in plotly:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df2 = df.pivot_table(index=pd.Grouper(key = 'Time', freq = 'H'), columns='Component', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).plot(kind='bar')

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Class', x=df2.index, y = df2.Class),
    go.Bar(name='System', x=df2.index, y = df2.System)
])

fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

Result:
[image: Result plotly]

Comment: pandas uses matplotlib for plotting. I assume the question is specifically for plotly outputs.

Comment: Yes, I am using panda. It works :-) anyway, can I use Plotly to do this ?

Comment: Sure, you can also plot the pivot table in plotly. I've added some example code.

Comment: @Aries Why do you ask for a plotly solution but accept a matplotlib answer?

Comment: @Mr.T I wondered about that myself. But the OP didn't technically ask for a solution from any specifc library since both `plotly` and `matplotlib` tags were missing. But the OP still used `plotly` in their own example, so I was lead to make the same assumptions as you.

Comment: To add to the confusion: the OP now accepted another matplotlib answer, after I added a plotly solution

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Hilarious =) Getting unaccepted is rough though. Here, have an upvote instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [px.bar](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/) after taking care of the data structure using [pd.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). Your provided dataset doesn't make much sense for you challenge as you would need a few more uniqe timestamps to show what you want, so I've added a few data points to your source.

#### Some central steps (complete code at the end):

```
# data munging using pandas
dfp = pd.pivot_table(df,index=pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='H'),
                     columns='Component',
                     aggfunc=len,
                     fill_value=0)

# plotly express figure
fig = px.bar(dfp, x=dfp.index, y=['Class', 'System'])
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': {0: '9:32',
                          1: '9:32',
                          2: '9:32',
                          3: '9:32',
                          4: '9:32',
                          5: '9:32',
                          6: '9:32',
                          7: '9:32',
                          8: '13:32',
                          9: '13:32',
                          10: '13:32',
                          11: '17:22',
                          12: '17:22',
                          13: '17:22',
                          14: '17:32',
                          15: '19:32',
                          16: '19:32',
                          17: '19:32',
                          18: '19:32'},
                         'Component': {0: 'System',
                          1: 'Class',
                          2: 'System',
                          3: 'System',
                          4: 'System',
                          5: 'Class',
                          6: 'System',
                          7: 'Class',
                          8: 'System',
                          9: 'System',
                          10: 'Class',
                          11: 'Class',
                          12: 'System',
                          13: 'System',
                          14: 'System',
                          15: 'Class',
                          16: 'Class',
                          17: 'System',
                          18: 'Class'}})

# data munging us pd.pivot_table
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
dfp = pd.pivot_table(df, index=pd.Grouper(key='Time', freq='H'), columns='Component', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

# plotly
fig = px.bar(dfp, x=dfp.index, y=['Class', 'System'])
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the suggestions, I pick a few lines from you guys here and resemble below code to achieve what I am looking for. Below are is using Plotly.

```
import plotly.express as px
df=series
#df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
Component_count = df['Component'].resample('s').count()
Time_Component_count = pd.DataFrame({'Time': Component_count.index, 'Component Count': Component_count.values})

fig1 = px.histogram(Time_Component_count, x='Time', y='Component Count', histfunc='sum', title='Histogram Chart')
fig1.show(renderer="iframe_connected")
```

[image]